# How do I access distutils version number?

Tags: python, distutils

I have a python package that I am building with distutils, and I use the version argument in my setup function like so (with other arguments besides the name and version):

```
setup(name='example_module', version='0.1.2', ...)
```

I am able to extract the version number from a module within the `example_module` package by calling:

```
import pkg_resources
version = pkg_resources.require('example_module')[0].version
```

How do I access this version number from a python script that is outside of this distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to have the version of the is package available in another python program outside of the distribution is to follow PEP 396. http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0396/

Any other script can access the version of a python package by running

```
python setup.py --version
```

and capturing the output. I use that in my Makefiles to extract the version number when generating the online documentation of my packages.

If your package includes any commandline utilities then make sure you include a `--version` commandline option. Then any script/program will be able to get your packages version after installation using that.

Comment: +1 for link to PEP396!  I hadn't seen that.  Running `python setup.py --version` is unfortunately not an option, however, since I'm trying to extract the version number from within my own program and I'd rather not run a whole separate process just to capture a version number

Comment: I was not sure if your reference to script was to what I would call a python program or to some other shell script. Edited your question to make that more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, the version number is a constant in the source of the package, the setup.py uses that value, and then anyone importing the package can read the version string.

Comment: So accessing this might be done like: `example_module.__version__`?  Or do you mean some other way of accessing a constant?